# Methods with high complexity in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube

How to list out the methods from one project with high complexity in SonarQube?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Do you mean for one module in a multi-module project?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. I am trying to get a list of all methods from the whole project which have high complexity.

Comment: and is this question about how to get these results from SonarQube, the actual server, or for the SonarLint Eclipse plugin? You need to be specific because otherwise G. Ann's answer is the answer based on how this question is worded.

Answer (score 1):

- Enable the method complexity rule for the relevant language. E.G. [Java](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AMethodCyclomaticComplexity)
- Run an analysis
- [Search for issues by rule](https://sonarqube.com/issues#resolved=false%7Crules=squid%3AMethodCyclomaticComplexity)

You will see an issue raised on each method with a complexity above the rule threshold.

Comment: Thank you G. Ann. But i was looking for a way in which i can find the whole list of methods which has high complexity in whole project. Is there any way in SonarQube to find this list?

Comment: @umashankarkumar I've described what's available.

Comment: @umashankarkumar This literally does that

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam..Thank you. I will check in the way you have suggested.

Comment: @Novaterata Thank you. I will try to find out in the same way as suggested by G.Ann.